# How an I make `git ls-files` work in subdirectories?

Tags: git, git-ls-files

I want to run `git ls-file --modified` to obtain a list of files with unstaged changes. I was surprised to find that it works in the root directory, but not in any subdirectory, where it only prints files from the subdirectory (in contrast to `git status`, for instance).

Steps to reproduce:

```
mkdir repo
cd repo
git init
touch file.txt
git add file.txt 
mkdir subdirectory
echo "foo" >> file.txt    # file now has unstaged changes
git ls-files --modified   # This prints 'file.txt'
cd subdirectory/
git ls-files --modified   # This prints nothing
```

How can I change git's behaviour here?

Comment: ls-files doesn't work for the parent, however it works for the sub directories.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default many git commands run with respect to your current working directory (git status, ls-files,...).

You can use `-C`:

```
git -C ../ ls-files --modified
```

if you want the command to run with respect to the git 'toplevel', you could run:

```
git -C $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel) ls-files --modified
```

from the man page of git:

> ```
>    -C <path>
>        Run as if git was started in <path> instead of the current working directory. When multiple -C options are given, each subsequent
> ```

**EDIT**
It also depends what kind of output you want, as @phd not. See below commands and output to understand the different options and their output:

```
> git -C ../ ls-files --modified
file.txt
> git -C $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel) ls-files --modified # wrt git toplevel no matter how deep you are in the tree
file.txt
> git ls-files --modified ../
../file.txt
> git ls-files --modified $(git rev-parse --show-cdup) # wrt git toplevel no matter how deep you are in the tree
../file.txt
```

Comment: The disadvantage of `git -C` in this case is that `git ls-files` shows modified files related to the root, not to the current directory. IMO a better way is `git ls-files --modified $(git rev-parse --show-cdup)`.

Comment: @phd: thanks for the tip; I added this to my answer.