# How to collect a name list from a sub-folder in git

Tags: git, github

use case is, the git repository is a [monorepo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monorepo), I want to know who worked on a sub-project in history and get the name list.

For example, I'd like to know who involved and merged the codes to this sub-folder `PackerBuildV1`.

Only need target on master/main branch.

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/PackerBuildV1

any hints for me?

Comment: are you looking for `git log --graph -- Tasks/PackerBuildV1/` ?

Comment: this command `git shortlog -n -s -- myfolder` does work for my idea.

Answer (score 1):

Since [`git ls-files`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files) does [respect your current folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56144986/6309), you can:

- clone the monorepo
- cd to the PackerBuildV1 folder
- use a [`git ls-files` + `git blame` combo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52644142/6309) to get the authors.

That is:

```bash
git clone monorepoURL
cd monorepo/PackerBuildV1 
git ls-files | xargs -n1 git blame --line-porcelain | sed -n
's/^author //p' | sort -d | uniq
```